# Pagination doesn't work with will_paginate. Could anyone help with this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I am currently using Rails 2.3.5. I installed will_paginate gem 2.3.16 as suggested in the will_paginate [github page](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Installation). But will_paginate is not being recognized when I use it and I always end up with an error. I have attached the screenshot of the error when used from the project console and have also included my gem list. 
[image: will_paginate error]
[image: gem list]

What am I doing wrong? Should i include any more configuration? or is there a better way of doing pagination?

Comment: Can you please post the terminal output in a more friendly and readable manner?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked at this issue (3 months ago?) it looked as if will-paginate was not being actively maintained, and wasn't compatible with rails 3.  So I changed to [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), which I've found causes me less problems. There's a railscast on kaminari [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari)  too